# `Required` does not remove `undefined` from class generic properties (bug?)?

Tags: typescript, generics

I stumbled accross the following situation for the standard [utility type `Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype):

```
type A = {x?: number;}
type B1 = Required<A>['x']; // number, OK
type B2<T extends A> = Required<T>['x']; // number, OK
class C1 {
  public f(x: Required<A>['x']) { // x is number, OK
    const y = x + 1; // OK
  }
}
class C2<T extends A> {
  public f(x: Required<T>['x']) { // x is number | undefined, NOT OK
    const y = x + 1; // ERROR
  }
}
```

I cannot imagine that this is expected behavior. Why is the `C2`-case different from the `C1`-case? I thought at first it may have something to do with generics in general, but only class generics seem to be affected since the `B2`-case works.

Can I do anything - other than explicitly saying something like `x: Exclude<Required<T>['x'], undefined>` - to make `x` (and potentially other properties of `A`) *really* required (i.e. not undefined)?

Comment: The compiler is not smart enough to do abstract reasoning with unspecified generic types.  Even so, sometimes human beings also makes mistakes with this kind of reasoning; for example, you can indeed pass `undefined` into `C2`'s `f` method, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nlg9lw) ("required" and "not `undefined`" are not the same thing).  So the compiler is correct to complain (although there are similar cases where it isn't).  Does this make sense to be written up as an answer? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hm ok thanks I see now by your example the difference between `C1` and `C2` (I think). But I still don't get the difference between `B2` and `C2`; should be the same thing in my view.

Comment: From [my example](https://tsplay.dev/Nlg9lw) you can see that they *are* the same thing; `B2` does not evaluate to `number`, it's a generic type that only evaluates to `number` if you write `B2<A>`.  If you write `B2<{x: number | undefined}>` then you get `number | undefined`.  It's exactly the same situation as `C2`.  Are you somehow seeing something different?

Comment: Kind of looks like [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71483186/2887218) is editing its way to what I'm saying here so I might not bother writing up another answer.  But please let me know if something's missing.

Comment: Hm that's interesting. When I add `type B3 = B2<{x: number | undefined}>;` to your example, in fact I get `number | undefined`. But when I do the exact same thing locally, I get `number`. Probably it has something to do with strict null checks or similar... Thanks anyway, I understand better now and will accept the existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer is that `T` is not equal with `A`. It means that `T` can be another type, that can do something and implements keys from `A`
if you want them to be equal you need to do this.

```
class C2<T extends Required<A>> {
  public f(x: Required<T>["x"]) {
    // x is number, OK
    const y = x + 1; // OK
  }
}
```

> Here, we’ll create an interface that has a single .length property and then we’ll use this interface and the extends keyword to denote our constraint:

[Generics docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

**UPD:**

`Required` makes from `{x?: number} -> {x: number}`.

**But** if call

`Required<{x: number | undefined}>`  The `x` still undefined.

When you pass `T` to generic then `field?: someType` converts to `field: someType | undefined`.

In your case you should get rid of undefined twice, the `?` and `undefined` type as well.

```
type FullRequired<T extends object> = Required<{
  [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined>;
}>;

class C2<T extends A> {
  public f(x: FullRequired<T>["x"]) {
    // x is number  OK
    const y = x + 1; // OK
  }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, `T` is not equal to `A`, but it extends `A`, so it must also have a property `x` with type `number` (and not `undefined`). Besides, your explanation would also be valid for the `B2` case, so why does `B2` work but not `C2`?